# Block visibility role section is missing

Tags: 8, blocks

I am doing development in drupal 8. All of a sudden, I see that block visibility role section is missing.

[image]

How can I bring the block visibility role section back?

Comment: Does it happen on all blocks? Where do the options in the screenshot come from? Is it a module? Does it happen when you're not using that module?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about an [issue in a third-party module, already reported in the project issue queue](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules/issues/3160347).

Answer (score 2):

There is a bug in Rules 8.x-3.0-alpha6 that hides the core block visibility conditions. Please upgrade to Rules 8.x-3.x-dev. See https://www.drupal.org/project/rules/issues/3160347