# Core Update to 8.9.4 Removed Block Visibility Options?

Tags: blocks

Recently updated core from 8.9.2 to 8.9.4, in doing so the options to place blocks on specify pages is now gone?

[image: block config after core update]

Comment: Those don't look like the normal options from core.

Comment: @4k4 Yes! Thank you for that, I spent way too much time tearing apart configs trying to hunt it down.

Answer (score 1):

I still see it
"Drupal core 8.9.4"
[image]

Comment: I recommend that this issue be closed because it is a duplicate of https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/296372/block-visibility-role-section-is-missing/296378#296378